# Does bluemix have an API to fetch application monitoring/metrics results?

Tags: analytics, monitoring, ibm-cloud

I see that bluemix has a service called Monitoring and Analytics. All I see from that service are dashboards. I am looking for the information the dashboards are providing in the form of an API. For example, if I want to be notified that my application is down or it is slow running, etc .. Is there a way for me to either receive such alerts or for an API that I can poll periodically?
thank you

Answer (score 3):

The Monitoring & Analytics service does not offer an API to retrieve its collected metrics. We realize that supporting a programmatic interface would be helpful and it's in our backlog to add that capability.

However, M&A does support the other part of your question regarding alerts. There should be an Events tab in your dashboard.  In the upper right corner, there's a dropdown to "Configure events policy". If you select it, you can enable Availability alerts ("Is my app down?") and/or Performance Monitoring alerts which are geared to the app's run-time type (Liberty, Node.js, etc.). In that same dropdown you can also "Configure notification". If you specify your email address in the notification dialog, you will start receiving alerts when your Bluemix application is down or running slowly.